# groupby and withhold information of one column based on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame consisting out of columns id, brand and count

```
Id  brand  count
1   Audi   3 
2   BWM    5 
2   FORD   3
3   AUDI   7
4   BMW    2
5   Audi   4
5   FORD   3
```

I would like to groupby id and only remain each id with the brand that has the highest count.
So in the end I would like to have the following:

```
id  brand
1   AUDI
2   BMW
3   AUDI
4   BMW
5   AUDI
```

I have something like this but that obviously is not working. So what would be the correct function or syntax to accomplish that? Thanks!

`data.groupby('id')['brand'].where(max('count'))`

Comment: Maybe `df.loc[df.groupby('Id')['count'].idxmax()]` ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC use [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Id')['count'].idxmax()]
```

[out]

```
   Id brand  count
0   1  Audi      3
1   2   BWM      5
3   3  AUDI      7
4   4   BMW      2
5   5  Audi      4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df=df.sort_values(['Id','count']).drop_duplicates('Id',keep='last')
Out[249]: 
   Id brand  count
0   1  Audi      3
1   2   BWM      5
3   3  AUDI      7
4   4   BMW      2
5   5  Audi      4
```